# Explicit formula for invariant inner product of the standard representation of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $V$ be a representation of a group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Given the standard Hermmitian inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $V$ we can always define a $G$-invariant inner product by
$$\langle x,y\rangle_\text{new} := \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \langle g x, g y\rangle$$
Can anyone calculate this explicitly for the standard representation of $S_3$? Is there any easy way to do this in general (for other reps of $S_n$) aside from the above method?

Comment: There is no "standard" inner product on an abstract vector space. Specifying an inner product on such a space is equivalent to specifying a basis of it, and bases don't always "come in the box." What basis do you want to use for the standard representation of $S_n$?

Comment: If by *standard representation* you mean the rep as $3\times3$ permutation matrices (as opposed to, say, the *regular representaion*), then what's wrong with
$$\langle(x_1,x_2,x_3),(y_1,y_2,y_3)\rangle=x_1\overline{y_1}+x_2\overline{y_2}+x_3\overline{y_3}?$$
Place the bars according to your taste of w.r.t. which slot the Hermitian inner product is linear as opposed conjugate linear.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The [standard rep](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation) of $S_3$ is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @whacka. So it is a subspace of the 3-d rep I talked about. And we can simply restrict the above Hermitian inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V = \Bbb C^2$ with the standard basis, and let $\rho: S_3 \to GL_2(\Bbb C)$ be given by:

$\rho(e) = I$, $\rho((1\ 2\ 3)) = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&-\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$,  $\rho((1\ 3\ 2)) = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&-\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

$\rho((2\ 3)) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$,  $\rho((1\ 2)) = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$,  $\rho((1\ 3)) = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

As one can readily verify, these are isometries under the standard Hermetian inner product, so for each $g \in S_3$ we have:

$\langle gu,gv\rangle = \langle u,v\rangle$, and our $G$-invariant inner product is the same as the standard one.